# windows cmd command Type interferes with reg entry named Type

Tags: types, cmd, registrykey

I need to modify the following registry key from a script: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\W32Time\Parameters\Type`

To do this I'm trying to run the following command from a .bat file:

`REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\W32Time\Parameters /v "Type" /REG_SZ "Sync" /f`

But I get `Error: Invalid syntax.`

I believe this is because Type is interpreted as the command [Type](http://ss64.com/nt/type.html) but I don't understand how to circumvent it, can anyone point me in the right direction on this? Or I'm just blind because I can't see the typo...

Comment: Try `REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\W32Time\Parameters /v "Type" /d "Sync" /t REG_SZ /f`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp wow that more than a typo... Thanks, if you put it as an answer I can accept it :)